# Can't connect to the storage server in the Google Compute Engine Tutorial for Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine

I'm following [Google's tutorial to integrate cloud storage with Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage). I'm having problems connecting to the Cloud storage server.

In the tutorial, you create the server using

```
$ gsutil mb gs://<your-project-id>
$ gsutil defacl set public-read gs://<your-project-id>
```

Afterwards, you configure the `config.js` file in the sample project to use the created storage server. Then, the following function (in the `image.js` file) is used as a request preprocessor to upload files to the cloud storage.

```
function processUploads(req, resp, next) {

  var numFiles = Object.keys(req.files).length;
  if (!numFiles) return next();

  function checkNext(err) {
    numFiles--;
    if (numFiles === 0) next();
  }

  Object.keys(req.files).forEach(function(key) {
    var uploadedFile = req.files[key];
    var file = bucket.file(uploadedFile.name);
    var stream = file.createWriteStream();

    stream.on('error', function(err) {
      uploadedFile.cloudStorageError = err;
      checkNext();
    });

    stream.on('complete', function() {
      uploadedFile.cloudStorageObject = uploadedFile.name;
      uploadedFile.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(uploadedFile.name);
      file.makePublic(checkNext);
    });

    stream.end(uploadedFile.buffer);
  });
}
```

The problem is that, when you upload a file in the form, neither the `complete` nor the `error` callbacks are called when you upload a file. It seems the storage server is simply not responding.

Can anyone help me make it work?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around a little more, I found out the files were actually being stored in the cloud. I was able to use the browse function in the Storage server session of the Google Compute Engine Console in order to see the files I uploaded.

But my callbacks weren't being called. After reading the source code, it appears that the sample code is outdated. One I replaced the event from `complete` to `finish`, as shown down below, everything started working perfectly.

```
function processUploads(req, resp, next) {

  var numFiles = Object.keys(req.files).length;
  if (!numFiles) return next();

  function checkNext(err) {
    numFiles--;
    if (numFiles === 0) next();
  }

  Object.keys(req.files).forEach(function(key) {
    var uploadedFile = req.files[key];
    var file = bucket.file(uploadedFile.name);
    var stream = file.createWriteStream();

    stream.on('error', function(err) {
      uploadedFile.cloudStorageError = err;
      checkNext();
    });

    stream.on('finish', function() {
      uploadedFile.cloudStorageObject = uploadedFile.name;
      uploadedFile.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(uploadedFile.name);
      file.makePublic(checkNext);
    });

    stream.write(uploadedFile.buffer);
    stream.end();
  });
}
```

I've also found a [gcloud package](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/pull/824) issue that shows there was a breaking change, but the [documentation is outdated](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.20.0/storage/file?method=createWriteStream) as it tells you to use `complete` rather than `finish` at the time of this writing.

Comment: What version of gcloud-node are you using? As of the latest stable release, `complete` is the way to go (however the next release that will no longer be true). `finish` is emitted when the writeable stream is finished writing data and `complete` is emitted when the request itself finished. It's possible that `complete` didn't fire because of a validation error.

Comment: I'm using version `"gcloud": "^0.16.0"` in my `package.json`.

Comment: Is there any way I can test wether it's a validation error?

Comment: If a validation error occurs, an `error` event should be emitted.